# F# Array2D - Extract Diagonals

Tags: matrix, f#, diagonal

Let us say I have a matrix

```
 [[0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0]
  [0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0]
  [2; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]
  [0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0]
  [0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0]
  [0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0]]
```

I want to extract the diagonals as a 1d array meaning `[|2;1;1|]` and `[|2;1;1;1|]`

For rows and columns, we have

```
matrix.[i,*] // The ith row
matrix.[*,i] // the ith column
```

Could we construct something similar for the ith diagonals in upward and downward direction?

Comment: What did you try up until now? This feel like an homework question.. Anyhow, take a look here: https://www.extremeoptimization.com/Documentation/Vector-and-Matrix/Matrices/Accessing-Rows-and-Columns.aspx

Comment: it is not. Something I need for a personal project.

Comment: I have already solved this with for-loops but I hoped to achieve something more compact.

Comment: I'm saying this because usually questions without any sample code to show the work done sends me that kind of alarm with the given context. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to use some external library, it's not going to get much shorter than the following.

```
let diag (mat: _ [,]) = 
    let l = min (mat.GetLength(0)) (mat.GetLength(1)) - 1
    [| for i in 0..l -> mat.[i,i] |]
```

I personally don't think that's an issue at all, but it's up to you. Of course, you could use `Array.init` or something else instead of the for loop, but I would prefer the stated solution.

Comment: if I understood the question right, this only returns a single diagonal. What is required is a method to extract all of them (with different lengths)

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see how the proposed `GetSlice` method syntax would apply to your scenario. On the other hand, the provision of an `Item` indexer property may be handy indeed to extract diagonals.

```
type 'a M = M of 'a list list with
    member me.Item i =
        let (M xss) = me in xss
        |> List.mapi (fun j ->
            List.mapi (fun k x ->
                if i = j - k then Some x else None )
            >> List.choose id )
        |> List.concat
```

Given a matrix as a list of lists:

```
let m =
 [[0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0]
  [0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0]
  [2; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0]
  [0; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0]
  [0; 0; 1; 0; 0; 0]
  [0; 0; 0; 1; 0; 0]]

M(m).[2] // val it : int list = [2; 1; 1; 1]
```